# How to use cordovaWebview in Worklight?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a requirement to load an external url on a view when a user clicks on a dojo listitem.
The view must contain a header followed by whole page from the external link. How can it be achieved using cordovaWebview if I am developing the app using Worklight v6? I tried to use cordova inappbrowser api to display the external link in browser but client is not satisfied with it and wants something like xcode webview api to achieve this. If I am not wrong cordovawebview uses Native webviews. How can I achieve this capability in my app ? Also,as I want my app to run in Android, iphone and Windows phone 8, what will be the step to achieve this feature in all three?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what did the customer not like when using InAppBrowser? Anything in specific?

Comment: First thing is that I am not able to show the header part on it and then it cannot open the pdf files. xcode webview is capable of opening pdf(from external links) in it. other than this inappbrowser has different behaviour in android and iphone simulator when using 'Location=no' property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to read the following training module and take a look at the sample project:

- [Integrating server-generated pages in hybrid applications](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/09_07_Integrating_server_generated_pages_in_Worklight_applications.pdf)
- [Sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/IntegratingServerGeneratedPagesProject.zip)

In this sample project you can display external content, for example - a website, "inline" in your application. This way you can also add a header (as it is part of your app) and below it the external content. It should work the same in all three environments you've mentioned: iOS, Android and Windows Phone 8.

However, in your comments you mention that you also need to display PDF files and this is whole nother story.

- iOS has a built-in PDF reader and so if opening a file, it should be detected and displayed by the internal PDF reader
- AFAIK Android does not have a built-in PDF reader
- No idea about Windows Phone 8...

If this external content you are talking about is in fact solely PDF files [you will need to create a Cordova plug-in](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova) that somehow displays these PDF files. Since Cordova plug-ins essentially mean writing native code, if you manage to get a PDF file displayed, you might be able to also create the same user experience (although I think the experience should be based on the OS nature (what the user expects) and not what customer expects).